# How to develop a library with a higher trial version of the application

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I did a library with react 16.8.8 and I have an application with react 16.8.2. Based on the Doc, both are able to work with the new hooks. I made a build in my library with webpack. Then I will try to import lib with npm link. But when I import my lib in components I have this error:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You'll probably have to show us some code.  Specifically where you're calling these hooks and how you're using this library.

Comment: You're not calling it inside the body of a function component?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to use hook in component created with ES6 style

```
class Sample extends React.Component {
    public render(){
       // hook call not allowed 
    }
}

const Sample = () => {
   // you can use hook here
}
```